# ClearCase snapshot view config spec when the ClearCase server is offline

Tags: clearcase

When ClearCase server is offline, and I'm having a snapshot view:

- where are the config spec stored?
- Will I be able to view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config spec is stored at the **[view storage directory](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_viewadm_dynamic_stgdir.htm)**:

> An individual view's config spec is stored in its view storage directory, in two forms:
>
> - Source format. The user-visible version, `config_spec`, contains only the series of config spec rules.
> - Compiled format. A modified version, `.compiled_spec`, includes accounting information. This version is created and used by the view_server process.

Even if the server is offline, you can still try and access the  `\\shared\view\storage\myView.vws` path associated to your view and read the `config_spec` file.

If the *network* is done though, and the view storage is not a local one (local to your host), then you would not be able to read it.

Check if `cleartool catcs` still work.

Comment: The unc path assumes that the offline host isn't the view storage host.  Also, the compiled spec may be a challenging read as it often contains s binary data.  Assuming that you aren't using include clauses, the text config spec should do.